# map cryptotoken on other BlockChain to ERC20 token on ethereum

Tags: erc-20, mapping, tokens

I am new to cryptotoken world. wanted to test some concept.

I want to create cryptotoken on Hyperledger blockchain say "HyperToken" and want to map/integrate with ERC20 token on ethereum blockchain. so when user buys a token through smartcontract on ethereum through ether,  he gets "Hypertoken" with following value

1 ERC20 token = 0.5 hypertoken.

Can anyone advice on how this can be achieved or any reference material to understand the flow.

Thanks and regards 
Sal